# Razor pages returning partial view, item passed in is null

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

I'm new to Razor and partials. Basically, my overall need is to be able to update a table when a user clicks a button.

What I'm doing as of right now is I click the button, an ajax function first calls a method to fill a dictionary with updated information, then call a function to return a partial view which is supposed to display this update information without causing my whole page to refresh.

**Ajax Code**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#AddContactQue").click(function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            var name = $('#contactName').val();
            var role = $('#contactRole').val();
            console.log(name+','+role);
            $.ajax({
                    url: "AddApplication?handler=AddContactToQue",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { name,role },
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                    },
                    success: function () {
                        alert("success");
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        $('#contactsTB').load('/AddApplication?handler=AppPartial');
                    },
                    failure: function () {
                        alert("failure");
                    }
                })
        });
    });
</script>
```

Upon completion I make an ajax call to update my partial.

From what I've read online the ajax `preventDefault` is supposed to stop any "postbacks" from happening, so my data in my code behind should not be getting lost.

The issue right now is that I fill my dictionary, then when it goes to update the partial the dictionary is null. Therefore, the partial returns an empty table with nothing inside.

**Update Info Method**

```
public void OnPostAddContactToQue(string name, string role)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("----------urlcount=-----"+appURLS.Count);           
            if(HttpContext.Session.GetString("selectedContact") == null)
            {
                string s = name + ",";
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("selectedContact", s);
            }
            else 
            {
                string l = HttpContext.Session.GetString("selectedContact");

                l += name + ",";

                HttpContext.Session.SetString("selectedContact",l);
            }



            if(HttpContext.Session.GetString("selectedContactRole") == null)
            {
                string s = role + ",";
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("selectedContactRole", s);
            }
            else 
            { 
                string l = HttpContext.Session.GetString("selectedContactRole");

                l += role + ",";

                HttpContext.Session.SetString("selectedContactRole",l);
            }

            contactQue = HttpContext.Session.GetString("selectedContact");
            contactRoleQue = HttpContext.Session.GetString("selectedContactRole");

            List<string> cList = contactQue.Split(',').ToList<string>();
            List<string> crList = contactRoleQue.Split(',').ToList<string>();

            for(int i = 0; i < cList.Count; i ++)
            {
                appContacts.Add(cList[i],crList[i]);
            }

            PopulateTools();

            Console.WriteLine(HttpContext.Session.GetString("selectedURLS"));
        }
```

**GetPartial Method**

```
public Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.PartialViewResult OnGetAppPartial()  
        {
            return new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.PartialViewResult{ViewName = "_AppPartial",ViewData = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewDataDictionary<Dictionary<string,string>>(ViewData,appContacts)};
        }
```

Upon hitting `OnGetAppPartial` the `appContacts` dictionary is null. I don't understand why it's being set to null since `preventDefault` is supposed to stop a page reload.

**_AppPartial.cshtml**

```
@model Dictionary<string,string>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody>
     @foreach(var s in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.Raw(s.Key + " - " + s.Value)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>  
</table>
```

I was following https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/325/partials-and-ajax-in-razor-pages as a reference.

Comment: What's `appContacts`? Looks like it's a class-level variable.  This is likely empty as MVC is stateless - ie all data is lost between each call (unless you jump through hoops to get around this).  Debug your C# and see what the value of appContacts is on the GET.

Comment: Your comment regarding preventDefault stopping a reload and appContacts being null shows the misunderstanding between the HTML page/javascript and the server-side code-behind (C# Razor).  As soon as your request (GET/POST) completes, the server side data is gone.  You'll need to re-get it from the database / storage.  Depends on what else is in your class of course.

Comment: You could add your partial view `return PartialView("_AppPartial, ...` to the end of the POST then your javascript will get the HTML in `success: function(html) {` then no need for a second call.

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense. I kept thinking about this as since preventDefault stops reload there would be no post or get sent to the server side. One solution i do have is since im saving the information in the session, i could fill the dictionary inside the OnGetAppPartial method. How would i implement your solution?

Comment: Move the `return` from OnGetAppPartial to the end of OnPostAddContactToQue then change `$.ajax` `success` to `success: function(html) { $("#contactsTB").html(html)); }`